PostgreSQLConfigurationExtension does not define or inherit an implementation extractParametersFromConfiguration(java.util.Map)'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.flywaydb.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLConfigurationExtension does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void extractParametersFromConfiguration(java.util.Map)' of interface org.flywaydb.core.extensibility.ConfigurationExtension.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1519)
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.flywaydb.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLConfigurationExtension does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void extractParametersFromConfiguration(java.util.Map)' of interface org.flywaydb.core.extensibility.ConfigurationExtension.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.flywaydb.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLConfigurationExtension does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void extractParametersFromConfiguration(java.util.Map)' of interface org.flywaydb.core.extensibility.ConfigurationExtension.
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.configure(ClassicConfiguration.java:1373)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.configureFromConfigurationProviders(ClassicConfiguration.java:1669)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.configure(ClassicConfiguration.java:1345)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.<init>(ClassicConfiguration.java:412)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.<init>(Flyway.java:100)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.load(FluentConfiguration.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 89 common frames omitted

Which version and edition of Flyway are you using?
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.20.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>10.20.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

If this is not the latest version, can you reproduce the issue with the latest one as well? (Many bugs are fixed in newer releases and upgrading will often resolve the issue)
latest version
Which client are you using? (Command-line, Java API, Maven plugin, Gradle plugin)
   <spring-boot.version>2.7.18</spring-boot.version>

Which database are you using? (Type & version)
PostgreSQL 16.4
Which operating system are you using?
Windows 11
What did you do? (Please include the content causing the issue, any relevant configuration settings, the SQL statement(s) that failed (if any), and the command you ran)
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      minimum-idle: 2
      pool-name: HikariPool-Postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxx_db?currentSchema=public
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
  flyway:
    enabled: true

What did you expect to see?
I hope it works properly

I used Maven helper to check and found the following conflicts, but I don't understand why this happened
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3975
